# Biased vs unbiased lax monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

There are two principal ways to define a monoidal category:

- The **biased** definition includes a unit object $I$, a binary tensor product $A\otimes B$, and a ternary associativity isomorphism $(A\otimes B)\otimes C\cong A\otimes (B\otimes C)$ and unit isomorphisms satisfying appropriate axioms.
- The **unbiased** definition includes an $n$-ary tensor product $(A_1\otimes\cdots \otimes A_n)$ for all $n\ge 0$ (where $n=0$ gives the unit $I = ()$), with associativity isomorphisms such as $((A\otimes B) \otimes () \otimes (C)) \cong (A\otimes B\otimes C)$ satisfying appropriate axioms.

The two definitions are equivalent in an appropriate sense (though this is a nontrivial coherence theorem).  However, this is no longer true for "lax" kinds of monoidal category, where the associativity and unit isomorphisms are replaced by not-necessarily-invertible transformations.  In the lax case, the unbiased definition seems to be more-studied, and is usually what people mean by a "lax monoidal category".  There are good reasons for this, but "biased-lax" monoidal categories, and more general biased-lax structures, do occasionally pop up.

In the unbiased case, there are only two consistent choices of direction for the transformations: $((A\otimes B) \otimes () \otimes (C)) \to (A\otimes B\otimes C)$ gives a **lax** monoidal category, while the opposite direction gives a **colax** one.  In the biased case, there are more choices: in addition to choosing $(A\otimes B)\otimes C\to A\otimes (B\otimes C)$ or the opposite, we can choose how to orient the two unit morphisms: either $A \otimes I \to A$ or $A \to A\otimes I$, and also either $I\otimes A \to A$ or $A\to I\otimes A$.  For instance, a **skew** monoidal category pairs $A\to I\otimes A$ with $A\otimes I\to A$.  (Thanks Maxime for pointing this out in the comments.)

In this question I am interested in biased-lax monoidal categories where the unit transformations go in the same direction, say $A\otimes I\to A$ and $I\otimes A\to A$.  It seems that it should be possible to identify a biased-lax monoidal category of this sort with a particular kind of unbiased-lax one, by defining the $n$-ary tensor product in terms of the binary one by right-associativity: $(A_1\otimes\cdots \otimes A_n) = (A_1 \otimes (A_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes (A_{n-1}\otimes A_n)\cdots ))$ (or perhaps left associativity, depending on which direction the biased-lax associativity map goes).  I have seen this claimed in print, and have even claimed it myself, but I have not seen a proof written out.  So my questions are:

1. Has anyone studied biased-lax monoidal categories of this sort (or related structures like biased-lax bicategories, biased-lax monoids in a monoidal bicategory, etc.) in detail?
2. In particular, is there a better name for them?  (The only reference I know of is the paper "$T$-categories" by Albert Burroni, who called "biased-colax" *bicategories* of this sort "pseudo-categories" — clearly not a good name in light of modern terminological conventions.)
3. (The main question) Has anyone written out a proof that biased-lax monoidal categories of this sort can be identified with certain unbiased-lax ones?
4. What is an intrinsic characterization of the unbiased-lax monoidal categories that arise in this way?  (I expect they should be the ones such that certain of the associativity maps happen to be isomorphisms.)

Comment: Re 2: Skew monoidal categories are an example of biased-monoidal categories which seem to 'ping' a bit more when searching google, but it depends on how you want to orient the unit morphisms.

Comment: @MaximeLucas Thanks!  I should have mentioned skew-monoidal categories and specified the direction of unit morphisms; I'll edit the question.  I think both unit morphisms have to go in the same direction for my question (3) to be true, which is not the case for skew-monoidal categories.  (The actual direction is then arbitrary, up to passage to opposite categories.)

Comment: There seems to be an answer to questions 3 and 4 for *skew* monoidal categories in https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06087: in that case, unbiased-(co)lax monoidal categories have to be replaced by (co)lax algebras over a slightly fancier Cat-operad, and there is a "certain of the associativity maps are identities" condition called being an "LBC-algebra" that characterizes the lax algebras arising from skew-monoidal categories in this way.

Comment: That is right.  You can restrict this to obtain an equivalence between left normal skew monoidal categories (those for which $l:ia \to a$ is invertible) and normal colax monoidal categories satisfying the LBC condition (when viewed as colax $L$-algebras).  (The corresponding multicategory result was described in Theorem 6.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06088)

Comment: This special case about left normal skew monoidal categories would, I suspect, also be a special case of the result you are after about biased (co)lax monoidal categories.

Comment: @john I think I see, thanks: a left-normal skew monoidal category is the same as a left-normal biased-lax monoidal category, and similarly in the unbiased case, because the invertible left unit can be oriented in either direction.  Coincidentally the left normal case seems to be sufficient for the application I had in mind (https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/4632/closed-category/?Focus=69165#Comment_69165), but I'd still like to know about the general biased-lax case.