# Generalization of monoidal category with tensor products of $n$ objects

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

I'm looking for a generalization of monoidal categories, say $n$-monoidal categories, s.t. an ordinary monoidal category is the $n=2$ case. For general $n$, naively it should consist (among other data) of a functor $ \otimes : \mathcal{C} ^{\times n} \to \mathcal{C}$ and a natural transformations satisfying some $(n+1)$-cocycle condition, just as the pentagon axiom can be thought of a 3-cocycle condition for the usual associator. I'm sure people have thought about this, but I can't find any literature.

So basically, I'm looking for a vertical categorification of an $n$-ary monoid (semigroup).

Question 2: What would be a braiding for such an $n$-monoidal category?

Comment: Is there a standard definition of n-ary monoid you could give a link too ? I've never heard of such a structure, but depending on its properties (ex: can it be described by an operads ?) there are very general way to categorify it (even come up with an $\infty$-categorical version)

Comment: @Simon Henry I haven't seen it either, but stumbled upon this wikipedia page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary_group , where you could forget about the inverse axiom.. (from what I read I think I rather want n-ary semigroups)

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688187/strongly-unbiased-symmetric-monoidal-category and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301527/biased-vs-unbiased-lax-monoidal-categories

Comment: So n-ary monoids are decribed by a non-symetric operads so they are "easy" to categorify, and you will have (by some general theory) a coherence thereom saying that every n-ary monoidal category is equivalent to a strict one. One way to get a definition is as follows: the free n-ary monoid on sets is a cartesian monads, so it naturaly extend to a monad (denoted M) on Cat. Strict M-algebras in cat are strict algebra for this monad, general n-ary monoidal category are pseudo-algebra for this monads.

Comment: Getting an explicit definition (with a finite set of axioms) requires to compute the first level of a resolution of this operads... which require a bit of work. But essentially you should just start from an isomorphisms for each axioms of n-ary monoids, and then add enough coherence conditions so that each pair of isomorphisms between one bracketing to another constructed by composing  the basics isomorphism you have chosed are equals.